# TSQL - While loop within select?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, while-loop

In SQL server

Ok, so I'm working with a database table in which rows can have parent rows, which can then have parent rows of their own.  I need to select the root 'row'.  I don't know the best way to do this.

There is a field called ParentId, which links the row to the row with that ID.  When the ParentId = 0, it is the root row.

This is my query now:

```
SELECT Releases.Name,WorkLog.WorkLogId 

FROM WorkLog,Releases
WHERE
Releases.ReleaseId = WorkLog.ReleaseId
and WorkLogDateTime >= @StartDate
and WorkLogDateTime <= @end
```

---

I don't really need the Release Name of the child releases, I want only the root Release Name, so I want to select the result of a While loop like this:

```
WHILE (ParentReleaseId != 0)
BEGIN
@ReleaseId = ParentReleaseId
END

Select Release.Name
where Release.RealeaseId = @ReleaseId
```

I know that syntax is horrible, but hopefully I'm giving you an idea of what I'm trying to acheive.

Comment: So I'm guessing there's more than one release with `ParentReleaseId` equal to zero?

Comment: Are you saying that the Releases table is hierarchicial, eg Release X has a predecessor, and then that release has its own predecessor, and so on? So the problem is to find the *original* release for any *later* release occurring within the specified dates?

Comment: Hopefully, you're on 2005 or later - can you confirm?

Comment: Yes there is more than one parent release = 0.  David yes you have that right.  I am on 2008, Damien

Comment: Looks like you got a good push in the right direction with the recursive CTE answer below. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example, which could be usefull:

This query is getting a lower element of a tree, and searching up to the parent of parents. 
Like I have 4 level in my table -> category 7->5, 5->3, 3-> 1. If i give it to the 5 it will find the 1, because this is the top level of the three.

(Changing the last select you can have all of the parents up on the way.)

```
DECLARE @ID int

SET @ID = 5;

WITH CTE_Table_1
(
  ID,
  Name,
  ParentID
)
AS(
  SELECT 
   ID,
   Name,
   ParentID
  FROM Table_1
  WHERE ID = @ID

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 
  T.ID,
  T.Name,
  T.ParentID
 FROM Table_1 T
 INNER JOIN CTE_Table_1 ON CTE_Table_1.ParentID = T.ID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Table_1 WHERE ParentID = 0
```

Comment: DARN, beat me to it with the CTE. Good job :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using these 'algorithms' a lot in this week :)

Comment: Yes, it is not just 4 levels or just 3 or what. It is recursive, searching up. I just wrote a small example.

Comment: BTW if somebody would like to test it, here is an sqlFiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad1f2/5  (valid on 24.08.2012)

Comment: Thanks, that will make it a lot easier to apply to my query.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
with cte as
(
  select id,parent_id from t where t.id=@myStartingValue
  union all
  select t.id,t.parent_id
  from cte
  join t on cte.parent_id = t.id where cte.parent_id<>0
 )
select * 
from cte
join t on cte.id=t.id where cte.parent_id = 0
```

and with fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5fa1/1/0

Comment: I think the anchor member of the CTE will have to deal with the date constraints of the OP's example query, won't it?

Comment: From what I understand the starting value is selected before, and the date constraint will be on that select.

Answer (score 0):

Using Andras approach, I edited the final select to directly give me the ID of the root release

```
WITH cte_Releases
( 
  ReleaseId, 
  ParentReleaseID 
) 
AS( 
  SELECT  
   ReleaseId, 
   ParentReleaseID 
  FROM Releases
  Where ReleaseId = 905

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT  
  R.ReleaseId, 
  R.ParentReleaseID 
 FROM Releases R
 INNER JOIN cte_Releases ON cte_Releases.ParentReleaseID = R.ReleaseId
) 

SELECT max(ReleaseId) as ReleaseId, min(ReleaseId) as RootReleaseId FROM cte_Releases
```

My problem now is I want to run through all @IDs (905 in that code) and join each record to a result